# How can I define an array of scanner input in C not in main()?

Tags: c, arrays, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define line 4

int array[line];      //This works perfect

int s = user input;    //assume the user typed in a value and I stored the value in s;

int array2[s];        //Error: Variable Length Array Declaration not Allowed at File Scope in C

  int main() {

}
```

I want to be able to create an array of s length. However, I am unable to type #define s as I do not know the length of s yet. It varies on the user's input.

Assume s indeed equals user input, I realize this is pseudo code.

This is to be compiled in C in the Linux Terminal only, thought to add that if relevant.

EDIT: I realized that my error was because my array was not declared in main(). Regardless, does anyone know how to do this not in main()? Hopefully this will help someone some day.

Comment: don't you want to use a scanf then to get the user input?

Comment: yes, assume 's' is the user input

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to get a user input of the length, you would use a scanf.

```
int s, array[line];
scanf("%d", &s);
int array2[s];
```

I believe that's what you want...

Comment: Oh. I am so sorry, I realized my error was because I did not declare array[s] in main(). Do you know if I should delete this Stack Overflow Post?

Comment: Ultimately that's up to you. If you feel like it will serve a purpose for others then  keep it up. Otherwise, leave it as you may

Comment: I will leave it up because I wonder if it's possible to declare an array of a variable (such as s) not in main(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> "how to do this not in `main()?`"

Easy to do in another function.

```
int foo() {
  int s;
  scanf("%d", &s);
  assert(s > 0); 
  int array2[s];
}
```

Not possible in global memory.

Comment: is rand == s?      How does this relate to the user input of s